# Verify Fundamental Solution of the 3 Dimensional Laplace Operator

Tags: distribution-theory, laplacian

I would like to verify that $\frac{1}{4\pi |x|}$ is the fundamental solution of the 3 dimensional laplace operator so that

$$
\triangle \frac{1}{4 \pi |x|} = \delta(x)
$$

---

### What I have tried:

I think my best approach is to apply the distribution to a function

$$
\begin{aligned}
    \triangle \frac{1}{4 \pi |x|}[\varphi] &= \delta[\varphi] \\
    - \frac{1}{4 \pi |x|} [\triangle \varphi] &= \delta[\varphi] \\
     - \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{4 \pi |x|} \triangle \varphi dx^3 &= \int_\mathbb{R} \delta(x) \varphi(x) dx^3 = \varphi(0)
\end{aligned}
$$
However the integral on the left has to be reinterpreted, because $\frac{1}{|x|}$ is not a schwarz function and it is undefined at 0.
So we have to use some combination of a convergece factor and a modefication of the region, maybe similar to this:
$$
- \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{4 \pi |x|} \triangle \varphi dx^3 = - \lim_{\varepsilon, \eta \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus B_\varepsilon(0)} \frac{e^{- \eta |x|}}{4 \pi |x|} \triangle \varphi dx^3
$$

I do not really care that much about the answer beeing super rigoros, if it works, it works. I only experimented with the convergence factor because I was stuck and thought introducing these things might help me.

I was hopeing that using integration by parts and a change into spherical coordinates I would get something like this (with volume element $4\pi r²$):

$$
- 4 \pi \int_\varepsilon^\infty \frac{1}{r} \triangle \varphi \: r² dx^3 = 4 \pi \int_\varepsilon^\infty \left( \triangle r \right) \varphi(r) dr - \left[ r \varphi \right]_\varepsilon^\infty \qquad (\varepsilon \to 0)
$$
The $\left[ r \varphi \right]_\varepsilon^\infty$ part is $\varepsilon \varphi(\varepsilon)$ and the integral should somehow evaluate to $\varphi(0)$, when using the spherical laplace operator $\triangle r = \frac{2}{r}$.

( I have also looked at other questions and answers from the math stackexchance, in particular [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076653/greens-function-of-laplace-operator), but I do not understand the answer. Also this is more about verifying that it is a solution than finding the solution. There are also many questions regarding the 2 Dimensional one.)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4224070/568204) of mine. I give a few approaches for proving it. You should take a look at the one I titles "Classical Approach". You seem to be going wrong with your integration by parts and spherical coordinates. Also, the fact that $\frac{1}{|x|}$ is indefined at $0$ is not an issue, because you're integrating over $\Bbb{R}^3$ (not $\Bbb{R}$ as you wrote), and here it is integrable near the origin (because the volume element for such radial functions is $4\pi r^2\,dr$, so the extra powers of $r$ save the day).

Comment: Oh, yes. I forgot the volume element! Thank you.